# Additional "in ...." keyword after loop/if-statement

Tags: swift, closures

I can't describe the syntax I'm trying to understand too well because I can't seem to find it now that I'm looking for it specifically, but in some codes I stumbled upon a syntax like:

```
for .... { in something
  someCode 
}
```

I'm not sure either if was in a for/while-loop or an if-statement but I can't understand this "in...."-syntax after the opening curly brace.

I hope this information was sufficient enough.

Greetings and thanks in advance <3

Comment: Can you post the actual code that you stumbled across? Or have you forgotten where you have found it already it?

Answer (score 1):

The `in` keyword is used in two places in Swift:

in `for` loops to denote what range/sequence you're picking values from, like

```
for i in 0..<10 {
   print(i)
}
```

and in the syntax for closures, for example:

```
[ 5, 8, 0, 9].sorted { i1, i2 in
  return i1 < i2
}
// -> [ 0, 5, 8, 9 ]
```

to denote the parameters you pass in to the closure. See https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

`in` is *not* used after the opening brace of a `for` or `if` statement.